# How to pass a variable to a closure

Tags: javascript, api, closures

I am using Decarta JS API PIN event handler

I am displaying pins on a map and the click event for each pin is fired correctly.  The trouble comes in when I try pass the pin id to the handler.  It ALWAYS displays the last id loaded regardless of which pin is clicked on.  My code for declaring the listener is:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < jsonObjects.devices.length; idx++) {
    var device = jsonObjects.devices[idx]
    deCarta.Core.EventManager.listen('click', function() {home.pinPushed(device.id);}, device.pin);
}
```

This is done in a loop through all the locations I am displaying.  They are displayed correctly at their respective coordinates, and logging the previous line clearly shows that each pin is declared with the correct id.  However, whenever I click on a pin, the **LAST id** declared is the only id ever passed to the handler:

```
home.pinPushed(device.id)
```

How do I get each pin to pass the unique id when the pin is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
deCarta.Core.EventManager.listen('click', 
 (function(id) { return  function (){home.pinPushed(id);}})(device.id), device.pin);
```

Beautify version :

```
 deCarta.Core.EventManager.listen('click', (function (id)
 {
     return function ()
     {
         home.pinPushed(id); //<---- id here is the closured variable
     }
 })(device.id), device.pin);
```

Explanation :

`Js` has a function *scope* ( not braces `({})` scope.)

Your `for` loop is *not* creating *ANY* scope/function.

What I was doing is to create execution context for each iteration.

for each iteration im sending the current `device.id` to a function which in turn , returns *another* function which closured the variable.

Comment: That works - Fantastic!  Thank you SO MUCH!!!!  Would you be so kind as to briefly explain why this works?